# Handling Mappings when migrating Get Index call from Transport client to Rest High Level Client

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

We are migrating from Transport Client to High Level Rest Client. How do we reconcile the difference in the `mappings` field of `GetIndexResponse` object returned from Transport client vs Rest High Level Client?

For transport client, we use this code to obtain the index information:

```
        GetIndexResponse response = client.get()
                .admin()
                .indices()
                .prepareGetIndex()
                .setFeatures(GetIndexRequest.Feature.MAPPINGS, GetIndexRequest.Feature.SETTINGS)
                .setIndices(indices)
                .get();
```

The response `mappings` field is a `ImmutableOpenMap<String, ImmutableOpenMap<String, MappingMetaData>>`
But for rest high level client, the `mappings` field is just a `Map<String, MappingMetadata>`.
Here is the code for High Level Rest Client:

```
        GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest(indices);
        request.addFeatures(GetIndexRequest.Feature.MAPPINGS, GetIndexRequest.Feature.SETTINGS);
        try {
            GetIndexResponse response = esClient.indices().get(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            return
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new SafeRuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

These are the response object classes:
Transport Client: `org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.GetIndexResponse`
Rest High Level Client: `org.elasticsearch.client.indices.GetIndexResponse`

Answer (score 0):

for mappings use the GetMappings request:

```
ImmutableOpenMap<String, ?> mappings = esclient.admin().indices().getMappings(new GetMappingsRequest()).actionGet().getMappings();
```

and you can also specify the indices you want.

EDIT: ah i see, you mean this:

```
client.indices().getMapping(new GetMappingsRequest().indices("index_name1", "index_name2"), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
client.indices().getSettings(new GetSettingsRequest().indices("index_name1", "index_name2"), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

when "client" is an instance of the High level REST client.

Comment: This looks like a call through `TransportClient` which we are migrating away from. Also, We need to get both settings, mappings for a specific set of indices using the new High Level Rest Client.

Comment: See the return type of these seemingly similar calls(One is Map<> other is Map<String, Map<>>):

Transport Client: ```ImmutableOpenMap<String, ImmutableOpenMap<String, MappingMetadata>> mappings = esclient.admin().indices().getMappings(new GetMappingsRequest()).actionGet().getMappings();```
vs

Rest Client : ```Map<String, MappingMetadata> mappings = client.indices().getMapping(new GetMappingsRequest(), RequestOptions.DEFAULT).mappings();```